# launchd with high disk usage

Tags: macos, launchd

launchd is producing a lot of I/O activity. In the last day and a half it managed to write 12 GB of data while reading 500MB.

I the logs I do not see anything suspicious. Any suggestion at where could I look?

Comment: You can use "live" tracking of R/W events of launchd with: `sudo iosnoop | grep launchd`. Some will be listed as *Unknown*, but maybe You'll find some big writes (5th column is size).

Comment: Could you edit this to include some details? What version of OS X? How are you measuring the IO of the launchd process?

Comment: Instances of `launchd` are the parent process of __all__ processes on OS X; `launchd` itself does very little but launch and manage other processes. Is it possible the measurement tool is mis-attributing disk activity of a child process with the parent `launchd` process?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to use the `lsof` utility

```
sudo lsof -p 1
# or 
sudo lsof -p $(ps -U root | grep -w "/sbin/launchd" | head -1 | awk '{print $1}')
```

EDIT
There are can be other user `launchd` processes running with different process IDs, run

```
ps aux | grep sbin/launchd
```

To check PIDs of other instances of `launchd`.

It should list opened files by `launchd`. Try that to find there something suspicious.
You can also try an app called [fseventer](https://aplawrence.com/MacOSX/fseventer.html), it shows read/write events to the filesystem, or use app like [Grand Perspective](http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net) or [Disk Inventory X](http://www.derlien.com/downloads/) to find this newly created huge file and investigate further what it is.

Comment: GrandPerspective is the new Disk Inventory X - http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net

Comment: Is launchd always running with PID 1?

Comment: System-wide launchd (as far as I know) always have pid 1. BTW, see edit, there are can be other instances of launchd with other pids

Comment: @user1855732 though launchd (1) will still be the parent process of the other instances.